# PHP Обработка многомерного массива $_POST

Tags: post, php

Есть HTML форма

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name[<?=$uniqid_1?>]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="tags[<?=$uniqid_1?>]" value="">

  <input type="text" name="name[<?=$uniqid_2?>]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="tags[<?=$uniqid_2?>]" value="">

  <input type="text" name="name[<?=$uniqid_3?>]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="tags[<?=$uniqid_3?>]" value="">
</form>
```

Таким образом с каждым name и tags я передаю идентификатор, которому эти поля соответствуют. Но дело в том, что такой массив не очень удобно обрабатывать в PHP из-за нарушения порядка ключей. Еще вариант - добавлять hidden элемент с uniqid, но мне кажется, что такой код будет менее красив. Какие еще есть варианты и какой используете вы?

Comment: я так делаю:

    echo $_POST['name'][uniqid_1];
    echo $_POST['tags'][uniqid_2];

Comment: Мне не нравится то, что нужно заранее знать, какие поля были в форме. В моем проекте, вместо name и tags могут быть любые другие поля из таблицы в базе. Можно попробовать поменять местами ключи, тогда будет проще, но хотелось бы посмотреть еще варианты.

Comment: А в чем проблема его обрабатывать?

    $keys = array_keys($_POST['name']);
    foreach($keys as $key){
    echo $_POST['name'][$key];
    echo $_POST['tags'][$key];
    }

Comment: Я использую MVC и мои модели, для обновления записей принимают одномерный массив вроде
array=('name' => 'value', 'tags' => 'value', ...)
Поэтому в контроллере надо делать обработку массива, что мне не очень нравится, т к усложняется логика. Но сейчас уже решил переделать модели принимать сразу массив с такими же ключами, как у post и обработку делать в модели.